# Mounting windows share error

Tags: samba, shared-folders, cifs

So from my ubuntu 14.04 system I run the followig command:

```
 sudo mount.cifs -o username=dana //192.168.1.4/Users /mnt/
```

It asks for sudo password an the the output:

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
Password for dana@//192.168.1.4/Users: 
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Now, the windows 7 pc is password protected but I provided the right password I am shore of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 questions here:

1) The no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864: You can solve this issue by `sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass` OR by running `pam-auth-update` and deselect "SMB password synchronization" option in the pam-auth-update UI. (ref. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186)

2) mount error(13): Permission denied: This is your Windows that is not allowing the mount. You should post this question on superuser.com and give all the information on how the network share has been set up.